# UIImageView: combine UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit and UIViewContentModeBottom

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

Is there a way to avoid image stretching in an `UIImageView` and aligning it to the bottom at the same time? Basically I want to obtain what would happen if it was possible to combine the  `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` and `UIViewContentModeBottom` `contentMode`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution on my own. This code resizes the `UIImageView` to its `image`'s size, and moves it at the bottom of its superview.

```
CGSize initialImageSize = imageView.size;

CGSize imageSize = imageView.image.size;
CGFloat aspectRatio = imageSize.width / imageSize.height;

CGRect imageFrame = imageView.frame;

if (initialImageSize.width / aspectRatio <= initialImageSize.height) {
    imageFrame.size.width = initialImageSize.width;
    imageFrame.size.height = imageFrame.size.width / aspectRatio;
} else {
    imageFrame.size.height = initialImageSize.height;
    imageFrame.size.width = imageFrame.size.height * aspectRatio;
}

CGRect parentFrame = imageView.superview.frame;
imageFrame.origin.y = (parentFrame.origin.y + parentFrame.size.height) - imageFrame.size.height;

imageView.frame = imageFrame;
```

Comment: Any way to not get the image view to move, just have the image push to the bottom of the UIImageView?

Answer (score 1):

### Constraint based approach

You'll want to constrain the `left`, `right`, and `bottom` sides of the `UIImageView` while ensuring the ratio of the size is the same as the `UIImage` that it's displaying.

```
UIImage *image; // allocate image object here
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[parent addSubview:imageView]; // add imageView to proper view with addSubview: here
UIView *superview = imageView.superview; // match width and bottom of self.superview
CGFloat ratio = image.size.width / image.size.height;

NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.f constant:0.f];
NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.f constant:0.f];
NSLayoutConstraint *rightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.f constant:0.f];
NSLayoutConstraint *ratioConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                       toItem:imageView
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                   multiplier:ratio
                                                                     constant:1.f];
[imageView addConstraint:ratioConstraint];
[superview addConstraints:@[leftConstraint, bottomConstraint, rightConstraint]];
```

This will emulate a combination of `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` and `UIViewContentModeBottom` but will resize the height of the `UIImageView` as well.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
    float newwidth;
    float newheight;

    if (image.size.height>=image.size.width){
        newheight=imageview.frame.size.height;
        newwidth=(image.size.width/image.size.height)*newheight;

        if(newwidth>imageview.frame.size.width){
            float diff=imageview.frame.size.width-newwidth;
            newheight=newheight+diff/newheight*newheight;
            newwidth=imageview.frame.size.width;
        }

    }
    else{
        newwidth=imageview.frame.size.width;
        newheight=(image.size.height/image.size.width)*newwidth;

        if(newheight>imageview.frame.size.height){
            float diff=imageview.frame.size.height-newheight;
            newwidth=newwidth+diff/newwidth*newwidth;
            newheight=imageview.frame.size.height;
        }
    }
```

Comment: When posting code, it is preferable to add a brief explanation of what it does and perhaps how it differs from other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a much easier way to do it.

```
imageView.contentMode = .Bottom
imageView.clipToBounds = true
```

This will prevent the image from resizing no matter what frame it is bounded in. And the clipToBounds part is important because it prevents the non resized image from going outside the imageView bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but a simple solution. On the UIImageView:

- Use the contentMode property to position the image. (in the current case UIView.ContentMode.bottom)
- Use the contentScaleFactor property of the UIImageView to scale the image in the content view.

This will maintain the aspect ratio, just calculate the scale you need. For scaleAspectFit:

`yourImageView.contentMode        = UIView.ContentMode.bottom
let relWidthScale                 = yourImage.size.width/yourImageView.frame.width
let relHeightScale                = yourImage.size.height/yourImageView.frame.height
yourImageView.contentScaleFactor  = min(relWidthScale,relHeightScale)`

If the UIImageView changes size, you can update the scale by adding an observer to the bounds property of the UIImageView or its container.